# Can certain expectations of behavior be part of an interface's contract?

Tags: code-quality, object-oriented-design, interfaces

Given the following code:

```
public interface IUserDataProvider {        
    ICollection<SomeClass> getSomeClassRecordsForUser(int idUser);
}
```

Is it possible to define (via documentation) an expectation that any implementing class returns null instead of an empty collection (or vice versa) when no records are found? I realize interfaces do not have explicit control over how they are implemented, but considering that interfaces are said to define a contract, I'm wondering how far the jurisdiction of that contract can rightfully extend.

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard library also documents stringent contracts for its interfaces. Like [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) which has quite a long list of behavior requirements.

Usually there are always some implied contracts when you have an interface. When you, for example, have a method `getNewestRecord()`, there likely is an (unwritten?) contract that it really returns the newest one, even though an implementation could *technically* return any record.

But when you create APIs for other people to use, it's generally better to follow the principle of least surprise. The behavior that null is returned when no records are found can be surprising for a consumer and the implementor of your interface. A better design would be to define the interface method with `throws NoRecordsFoundException`. That way it should be clear to both implementors and consumers what behavior is expected in that case. Also, the consumer can hardly forget to handle this case properly, because a try/catch block is required. That will likely save you from some NullPointerExceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's possible to document an interface's expected behaviour in prose. But as long behaviour is only documented in prose, there is no guarantee that implementations will actually honour these requirements.

Right now I can think of two alternative ways of specifying expected behaviour in such a way that it becomes verifyable / testable:

1. Specify expected behaviour as a unit test and make the unit tests available to the end user:

   ```java
   @Test public void getSomeClassRecordsForUser_NeverReturnsAnEmptyCollection() {
       IUserDataProvider provider = …;
       Collection<SomeClass> result = provider.getSomeClassRecordsForUser(…);
       Assume.assumeNotNull(result);
       Assert.assertTrue(result.count() > 0);
   }
   ```

   I've learnt about this approach from the book, ["Growing Object-Oriented Software Guided By Tests"](http://www.growing-object-oriented-software.com/code.html). Basically, interfaces are characterized as "static" contracts ("What parts is a component made out of?"), with unit tests being the "dynamic" counter-parts ("How does a component interact with others?").
2. Use Design By Contract. Some languages support this directly (e.g. Eiffel), others support it through a library and/or compiler extensions; e.g. with .NET's Code Contracts:

   ```csharp
   [ContractClassFor(typeof(IUserDataProvider))]
   public class IUserDataProviderContract
   {
       public ICollection<SomeClass> GetSomeClassRecordsForUser(…)
       {
           Contract.Ensure(result == null || result.Count > 0);
       }
   }
   ```

   (Whenever program execution crosses a method boundary, pre-conditions and post-conditions are verified. Depending on the language and/or library used, these check may even be performed at compile-time.)

Comment: Great answer. If I could mark two responses as answers, I'd include this one too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**In laymans' words:**

- An empty collection is **more elegant** because the same code you use for traversing a populated collection, works fine with an empty one, only that nothing is processed. Example: a `for each loop`.
- An empty collection is a **valid object**. Not having items is part of the valid state of a collection.
- If having no items violates the **business rules**, then add a `throw  a NoDataFoundException` clause to the method signature in the interface
- If for some reason you really want the method to **return null** in case no records are found, then name the method  `getSomeClassRecordsForUserOrNull()`, but **I don't recommend it**.

**EDIT: the last two points** are ways to let the **implementors** know you expect null instead of an empty collection.

Comment: Great information, but it doesn't really answer the question as it pertains to interfaces imposing expectations on their implementors.

Comment: @Patrick I edited the answer to make it clear.